# Is there a Python language specification?

Tags: python, specifications

Is there anything in Python akin to Java's JLS or C#'s spec?

Comment: I Googled it too and found a Wikipedia article and the Python Language Reference.  These are hardly a specification, which he is looking for.

Comment: @S.Lott Yes actually I did Google it, not that it matters, these are the types of questions that SO is here for. Instead of a snippy comment maybe you could try answering helpfully.

Comment: Why was the Google result of a Python Language Specification unacceptable?  What was wrong with it?

Comment: @S.Lott because it did not answer the question. Google gave me a wiki article on the PLR and the PLR itself. It did not tell me there was no formal spec nor did it say there was. It remained unclear. Furthermore, I thought this would be a good question for SO seeing as SO is MEANT for these types of questions.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's no specification per se. The closest thing is the [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/), which details the syntax and semantics of the language.

Comment: How is the PLR not a specification? It is not a mathematically formal specification, but then neither is the ISO C or ISO C++ Standard.

Comment: @Yttrill Maybe it was different when this answer was posted?  Right _now_, it does look like a formal specification, in section 5 (Expressions) and onward.  Sections 1-4 just look like detailed descriptions, rather than a spec.

Comment: I think the Python Language Reference is just a reference specified for CPython?

Comment: CPython is the default/standard implementation, so it's a pretty darn good reference!

Comment: CPython specific implementation details are generally appropriately qualified in the language reference and the standard library reference. As other compliant implementations like PyPy, IronPython and Jython find areas they have a problem with, they seek clarification from python-dev as necessary (the C API, reference counting and the GIL are all CPython implementation details, for example). We sometimes even find obscure CPython bugs this way.

Tests covering such areas are flagged as "cpython_only" in the regression test suite, which is also shared across the major implementations.

Comment: @Yttrill If it can change at will, and it just records the choices of CPython, it's really documentation, and not a specification. The ISO standards are specs because they are the source of truth.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the [Python Reference](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, python is defined by its implementation.

Comment: Not true -- what's generally considered the de facto reference implementation (CPython) has some aspects that are NOT part of the Python Language (as defined in the Reference), such as reference counting, the GIL, &c, and other perfectly correct implementations of Python (such as Jython and IronPython) do NOT mimic these parts of CPython. So the PLR is closer to a specification, than any single implementation out of the several ones available can be.