# Is there any builtin Python function purely written in Python?

Tags: python, function, cpython, built-in

The function definitions for built-in functions such as `print`, `input`, etc., cannot be seen because they have been written in C. Is that the case for all built-in functions, or is there any built-in function that has been written in Python?

Edit: I am specifically talking about the CPython implementation.

Comment: That would depend on the specific Python implementation, just as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451929/base-language-of-python

Comment: Define "builtin". Python comes with a vast default library, some of which is written in Python.

Comment: Specifically for CPython - it is open-source, and you can examine it to answer your question

Comment: @deceze I mean the ones that are listed with `dir(builtins)`

Comment: I would think that they're probably all in C. But you could of course go through them one by one and see if you find one that isn't. Not sure what that exercise would be good for though…

Comment: A Stack Overflow question should be about _a specific problem you actually face_. What practical problem could an answer to this question _possibly_ help you solve?

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the same question a few weeks ago. Here is what I tried :

```
import inspect

for builtinname in dir(__builtins__):
    try:
        builtin = getattr(__builtins__, builtinname)
        src = inspect.getsource(builtin)
        srcfile = inspect.getsourcefile(builtin)
        print(f"Source for {builtinname} is in {srcfile} :")
        print(src)
    except TypeError as e:
        # inspect.getsource throw a TypeError when called on a builtin
        # it is not a documented behavior
        print(f"Source cannot be found for builtin {builtinname}")
```

The only builtins attribute with python source availaible is `__loader__`. When you look about it you understand that it is not really a builtin.

So the final answer to your question is no. There is no builtin written in pure Python in the CPython implementation.