# How can OpenCV work with python although it is written in C++?

Tags: python

From the internet I have learnt that Python does not have any standard modules to access the webcam. In order to capture a photo using the WebCam, we need to use an open source module called opencv (cv2 for python) which is written in C++. My question is why does python interpreter not throw an error when a piece of C++ code is used inside a Python code? How can it interpret something which is not python?

Comment: 1. The de facto reference implementation of Python is written in C and is *literally* called cpython. 2. How do you think Python talks to the *operating system* written in C/C++? 3. All of this is covered very well elsewhere, e.g. [here on this very site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451929/base-language-of-python), or [here](https://realpython.com/python-bindings-overview/), or [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), or...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

The python functions act as wrappers, meaning they just provide a python interface but behind the scenes they just execute the C++ code. So all you need is some code that lets you interpret the data that is sent from C++ and find the python equivalent like https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html and you're done. Though in case of OpenCV people have already done that for you so you can use the python stuff as if it were written in python.